# How do I use gitstats by hoxu?

Tags: git, code-statistics

I want to monitor my repo on gitub, so I'm trying to use [gitstats](http://gitstats.sourceforge.net/) in order to see some stats like how much code has been changed. I added gitstats to my repo, but after that I'm not sure how to actually create the html files.

when I use a shell from the github on windows application, or even cmd, when i try to run gitstats, ./gitstats, $./gitstats, none of it works.

> gitstats does not currently need to be installed; it's used right
>   from the directory (it also assumes some files like the stylesheet are
>   in .)
>
> Suppose you have a git project at /mnt/src/git/project and you want to
>   save the statistics to ~/public_html/project
>
> You would run: $ ./gitstats /mnt/src/git/project ~/public_html/project
>   (go grab a cup of coffee if it's a large project :) $ sensible-browser
>   ~/public_html/project/index.html

even when i try the stuff from the gitstats install file, it doesnt work.

any idea how i could fix this? 
thanks

Answer (score 1):

this is an old post, but might come in handy anyway.

On Windows use python gitstats instead of just gitstats. You can also use regular Windows paths with backslashes. Point to your repository root, where the .git folder is, not to a branch.

So you are going to invoke the following command (assuming you are in the GitStats directory and python is on your PATH):

If you have your python on the PATH variable and you're in the GitStats directory, use the following syntax

python gitstats C:\path_to_local_repo\ C:\path_to_output_dir\

Hope this helps